# Laravel 5.8 Mailgun EU endpoint configuration not working

Tags: laravel, mailgun

I'm sending emails from Laravel (5.8) using Mail and Mailgun.

There are no issues when sending emails to the sandbox, however in production I cannot get emails to send from my domain. I've basically worked out this is due to the EU end point however even when I configure the end-point guzzle is still trying to send from the default.

Any reason why the default is still used?

**failed_jobs exception:**

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST
>   https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mydomain.com.au/messages.mime` resulted in
>   a `404 NOT FOUND` response: {   "message": "Domain not found:
>   mydomain.com.au" }

This endpoint should be api.**eu**.mailgun.net/v3

services.php

> 'mailgun' => [
>
> ```
>     'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
>     'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
>     'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'api.eu.mailgun.net/v3'),
> ],
> ```

.env file

> MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
>
> MAILGUN_DOMAIN=mydomain.com.au
>
> MAILGUN_SECRET=2.....................a
>
> MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=api.eu.mailgun.net/v3

Comment: Laravel 5.6 users: Mailgun endpoint config was introduced in 5.7 and backported to 5.5, but not 5.6 AFAICT. I only use the eu domain, and while I am not recommending doing what I do, currently I just patch the code as a build step like this: `sed -i 's#https://api.mailgun.net/v3/#https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/#'  /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Transport/MailgunTransport.php`.

Answer (score 5):

From my (working) .env:

```
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=your-in-mailgun-for-eu-configured-subdomain.yourdomain.com
MAILGUN_SECRET=your-key-0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=api.eu.mailgun.net
```

Notice the missing /v3, you dont need that. But judging from your info you have a different error:

You forgot to `composer install` on your server and still use the old package.
Because:

In vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Transport/MailgunTransport.php:51

`$this->endpoint = $endpoint ?? 'api.mailgun.net';`

...gets called from vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/TransportManager.php:138

```
        return new MailgunTransport(
            $this->guzzle($config),
            $config['secret'],
            $config['domain'],
            $config['endpoint'] ?? null
        );
```

...directly references config/services.php -> mailgun -> endpoint

So the only thing, that could lead to your error, is the old composer module.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I see:

1. It does not matter from where you receive the answer, because there could be redirects in between. I would ignore that at this point.
2. Your MAILGUN_DOMAIN looks wrong. I have an old one looking like this: "sandboxaff30js632kjh4beb94e3efce3f8d4dc0**.mailgun.org**"

From my experience I remember, there where some issues with EU locations.

And yours looks like it is wrong, but could be that you have that one. Dunno.

Comment: If I use my sandbox environment, there is no issues as it's in the US domain. To be honest I've tried everything, so I gave up in the end and changed my mailgun domain from EU to US and it works fine. My domain is a hosted subdomin actually - mail.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

Myend point with out /v3, look like this MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=